# Do the Passive Shields of the Hero Alts have different hitboxes?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

I can't find any place to visually see the hitboxes/hurtboxes of the passive shields of Link (and his variations), and Hero and their alternate costumes.

What I'm wondering is whether the different sizes of shields of the Hero alts affect the hitbox of the shield?

[image: Hero alts crouching]

[Additional Image (standing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcFGn.jpg)

Notice how DQ8 Hero's shield is MUCH taller than e.g. Erdrick's small shield. Does this have any nonzero in-game affect?

I tried experimenting a bit and there doesn't seem to be any difference, but I want a technical answer from the source code :)

---

*Bonus question: is the shield active at ALL times, or only when standing idle and when crouching?*

Comment: In regards to your bonus question, the passive shield should also be active when walking (but not dashing or beginning/ending dash). Poking around for some good resources on their shield sizes atm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want a technical answer from the source code :)

Very well.

[image: Hero params for shield]

As you can see, only one set of parameters exists for Hero's shield, not one per costume.

Comment: This answer would benefit from a citation.

Comment: Hm I'll have to determine if I'm allowed to link to the source, it might be private.

Comment: You finally replied :D! Thank you so much, I've been waiting 3 months for this. Your expertise is much appreciated!